# How to share binaries between development teams using VS2012 and TFS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

We are a team composed of many developers working on two solutions (solution *.sln* in the Visual Studio sense). We use Visual Studio 2012. Most developers have access to only one solution but need binaries (and .h/.lib) from both.

We are moving toward the use of Team Foundation 2012 but previously used Visual SourceSafe 6.0.

We **don't want** to keep the binaries on the database (that would however allow developers to simply get them via a GLV. But life is not so simple...)

We need:

1. Branches and binaries (from both solutions) in each branch. So if one develops in branch "1", he/she needs to use other solution binaries from branch "1".
2. No binary pushed into database (since they can be rebuilt from code we don't want to increase the size of the database uselessly.)
3. An easy way to obtain the up-to-date binaries (if not GLV, pre-build event?????? or something like this.)
4. The possibility for the developers to keep the version of the binaries they have without getting the up-to-date version.

**I strongly believe that there is a way to do what we need.** After all we are surely not the only ones to have isolated teams that rely on other teams' binaries. I just don't know how to do it.

**EDIT:** *GLV* means "Get Latest Version". Sorry for the undefined acronym.

Comment: If developers don't have access to the solution and the binaries are not in TFS, I don't see how you can solve this problem just using TFS. Apart from size do you have any other reasons not to store the binaries in the database, as that would allow what you need?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Get Latest Version

Comment: stuartd, you are probably right for the fact that VS/TFS alone are not sufficient. The size of the DB is the mean reason.

Comment: @dom_beau do you have a build server? Your teams could get the binaries from the build output..

Comment: Seems fine. I guess the output from the build server is what I call a **binary repository**...

Comment: @dom_beau This cheat sheet on binary repositories might be of interest - http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/binary-repository-management

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the binaries into source control at various stages: releases, sprint ends, etc. Label the result of each version checked in.

The "other team" can take a branch from these binaries at particular label levels. They never need to know about the later labels until they're ready for them.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, we don't want to keep the binaries under source control. (It would be too simple!)

Comment: That's what _I'm_ about to do, and to some extent, it's what you'll have to do with third-party binaries if you want to use the hosted TFS 2012 service. Just don't check in every version of the binaries. Only the "released" versions.

Comment: Well, if I don't check them in, they won't be available to developers who will have to get them from the database. With that scenario, developers will have to **get binaries directly from the repository folders**, right?

Comment: First of all, why are you saying binaries in the database. Why would you have your binaries in a database? Second, do developers on the "other team" need or want to see every change made by their colleagues? You probably want to release your binaries once they're tested, right? And maybe only once a week or so. The other team can decide which release they want to use.

Comment: All code is built ~daily. Team A doesn't need bin from Team B but Team B needs bin from Team A. We **don't** want to put bins on the DB but we rather want to find a way to sync bins from A with the code from team B for a given build. Using "*check in but keep only last version*" with VSourceSafe was the way we used to do before. But we are moving to TFS. We want to find a way to do that, even if this scenario involves the use of another app (+TFS +VS) like copying files to a common folder. **I just want to make sure I'm doing it right.**

Comment: You still haven't made clear: does Team B need to see _daily_ builds from Team A? If so, then the best would be to just use a file share.

Comment: Sorry... Yes, all build has to be seen and available as the up-to-date build. By *file share* you mean a folder (located on a file server) where all bins and header files are stored? So this has to be done in addition to work done by TFS?

Comment: Yes. TFS has nothing to do with sharing binaries. A simple file server will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Part of developers advise to use nuget.